# Import Shutil module arttribute

Tags: copy, shutil, copytree

I tried to use **shutil** module and copytree attribute. But it is not working and the commands box is empty. I import copytree and still not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not working"?  Are you getting an error message?  Do you have any code you could share?  What are you actually trying to do?  If you could clarify what your question is, what you've tried so far, and where you got stuck, that would be really helpful.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This is what I have got.

Comment: AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute'copytree'

Comment: And this is when I put shutil.copytree in my script.

Comment: I typed import shutil then from shutil import copytree.

Comment: The pop up window is empty. Nothing is there. Copy or copytree are not there.